# Animate bootstrap carousel content into view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, css-animations

I am trying to animate content in the bootstrap carousel, for example when you change a slide the content inside fades into view from a certain direction, after the background image.

I am not sure which path I should take with this if anyone has any suggestions.

For example this design has the same effect on the slider content I am looking for:
http://cleancanvas.herokuapp.com/

I have looked everywhere and there doesnt seem to be a tutorial on this anywhere.

Comment: Just to be sure... the content of the carousel is displaying but the images are not changing?

Comment: Images change as well, just like the example. Maybe there is a 3rd party plugin I can use instead of the bootstrap carousel?

Comment: Really don't know how to do this.... Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great solution, works almost perfectly out of the box.

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/